# Showing child categories

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories

HI I want to show some posts of category X but ONLY of this category but not child's categories too.

```
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;

$args = array( 'numberposts' =>-1, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 3 );     

$myposts = get_posts($args);    

foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
```

How I should do it? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' =>-1, 'offset'=> 0, 'category__in' => 3 );
```